# How can I pass on my Bash loop variable to the Perl interpreter?

Tags: perl, bash

I'm trying to modify some scripts with a combination of Bash and Perl. The trouble is that Perl thinks that `$index` is its own variable, which is never defined:

```
for index in {1..25}; do
    perl -pi -e 's/\d+/$index/' cmd_$index.sh;
done
```

Is there a way to make `$index` wear its Bash cloak within the Perl one-liner?

Comment: `$index_` is a valid symbol name in both Perl and bash. Maybe you want to use a different delimiter for the `s///` operator?

Comment: @mob : Yeah, I was going to change that... was trying to make it more readable and fudged things up in the process :|

Comment: @mob : Regex delimiters changed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Squeeze an `export index;` in the `do` loop. Refer to [`$ENV{index}`](http://p3rl.org/var#%25ENV) in the body of the Perl program.

Alternatively: Use the double quotes `"… $index … "` to interpolate the shell variable into the expression that makes up the body of the Perl program. In case you want to expand this one-liner, take care to properly escape Perl expressions, such as `$` on variable names, and perhaps backslashes, so that are interpreted by Perl, not the shell.

Comment: That's the best, _provided_ `index` has been exported from bash. You can do that before the loop or during it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `"` instead of `'`. The bash can then substitute the variable before perl sees it.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes and $index will be interpolated before the -e string is passed to Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example (though not in the terms of your problem - sorry!):

```
generatep() {
    perl -e '
        $_stem=$ARGV[0];
        $_ctx=$ARGV[1];
        $_role=$ARGV[2];
        $i=$ARGV[3];
        $ct=$i + $ARGV[4];
        while ($i < $ct) {
            print "user=$_stem$i,$_ctx,$_role\n";
            $i++;
        }
    ' ${stem} ${ctx} ${role} ${startix} ${count}
}
```

Comment: Isn't that likely to interfere with Perl's `-pi` handling?

Comment: It's worked well for me! You don't need to export the variable either. It works with vars declared locally inside your script.

Comment: i.e. this way of passing vars to perl doesn't affect "-pi". Works fine. My use of a loop in this e.g. may affect "-pi" but, it's just an e.g.

Comment: My comment was a (too?) subtle hint that you weren't properly addressing the question…

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem here is that the bash shell globs do not support ranges. For some reason, I thought they did. No matter, perl supports ranges just fine:

```
perl -pi -e '
    BEGIN { @ARGV = map "cmd_$_.sh", 1 .. 25; } 
    my ($index) = $ARGV =~ /(\d+)/;
    s/\d+/$index/'
```

A little bit clumsy, but it's all one language anyway.

Comment: Did you know that the `BEGIN` block could wedged in between the Eskimo kiss :) ? : `$ perl -e '... } BEGIN { ...'`

Comment: @Zaid Maybe so, but that's sacrificing a lot of logic to save one curly bracket worth of typing. =P